# Detect if user enters or leaves a region - geocoding

Tags: iphone, ios, geolocation, core-location

I'm starting with geocoding. And I have a lot of doubts.

I'm able to do forward and reverse geocoding (I guess, its not perfect).

And now, I'm trying to detect if user (device) enters or leaves a region. For that, I picked up apple's sample code "[Regions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Regions/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010726)". The sample uses `regionMonitoring`. I already try it in a device, but its not working well. I set a region with 25 meters radius, and when I left the region (walking) doesn't happen anything.

My question is: there is another and better way of doing this, detect if user enters or leaves a region, than `regionMonitoring`?

Can someone help me here??

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to calculate the distance between two `CLLocationCoordinate2D` it is easier than I though:

```
- (CLLocationDistance) DistanceBetweenCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)originCoordinate andCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)destinationCoordinate {

    CLLocation *originLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:originCoordinate.latitude longitude:originCoordinate.longitude];
    CLLocation *destinationLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:destinationCoordinate.latitude longitude:destinationCoordinate.longitude];
    CLLocationDistance distance = [originLocation distanceFromLocation:destinationLocation];
    [originLocation release];
    [destinationLocation release];

    return distance;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could keep the user-location tracking running in the background ([here is a good tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-multitasking-background-location/)) but keep in mind this can be heavier on battery use than regionMonitoring.

Comment: thanks its a good tutorial. But tracking user-location I'm already able to do. The point is, using user-location, to know if he is in a region or area, in a location neighborhood.

Comment: if you know the user location, and the center of target region, cant you just calculate the distance?

Comment: YES, that's the idea. Isn't there a tool to do that?? Thanks

Comment: its simple to calculate the distance using the equation: d = sqrt((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2), x and y being the gps longitude and latitude or the user and the target.

Comment: It gives me unreal values! And it is obvious. The formula that You gave me is for planar coordinates. Has you know the world is rounded, so it must be calculated another way, (with spherical coordinates, i gues). If you are interested, check this [link](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-vincenty.html). Thanks anyway

Comment: I got it..
tomorrow I will post my answer.

Comment: please do, cause i am doing it the way i told u (and it works) so i want to check your solution, maybe it will help me too.