# How can we know that map Coordinates are in current region or not in current region?

Tags: iphone, xcode, dictionary, region, coordinate-systems

I am working on map view app.I want know that how we can identify that coordinates are in my current region(Map region that bound with screen) or outside of it.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have different options. You can see this sample code from apple: [Regions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Regions/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010726). That, has I understand, check the device position by the antenna's position.

Or tracking device position, and check if is inside a region defined by You. Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819678/detect-if-user-enters-or-leaves-a-region-geocoding)

If you find a better solution, please let me know.

**EDIT:**

To check if a coordinate is visible in the map try using this:

```
// Your coordinates - Lisbon for example
float lisbonLatitudeValue = 38.7069320;
float lisbonLongitudeValue = -9.1356321;

CLLocationCoordinate2D lisbonCoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lisbonLatitudeValue, lisbonLongitudeValue);

if (MKMapRectContainsPoint(mapView.visibleMapRect, MKMapPointForCoordinate(lisbonCoordinates)))
{
    // do something
    NSLog(@" - Lisbon is visible");
}
else {
    // do something
    NSLog(@" - Lisbon is not visible");
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi Frade Thanks for Answer.But that was not what i am looking for.i want check that my saved coordinates is in current region or not.Like,I have one pair of latitude and longitude and i want to check that is it in current region or out of it.

Comment: Ok I get it. So what do you mean by region!? a country!? a city? a circular region?? a coordinate?? what do you have?? Try be more specific in your question..

Comment: Hi Frade i find something like method.

Comment: Hi Frade i find something like method.
[mapView isCoordinateInVisibleRegion:myCoordinate]
But I don't know how it's work.if you have any clue than tell me.

Comment: Take look at following url.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197398/how-do-i-determine-if-a-coordinate-is-in-the-currently-visible-map-region/1254786#1254786